# Workload Memory Bandwidth Comparison Inconsistency

Tags: x86, perf, memory-access, intel-pmu, memory-bandwidth

I have an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz` (`Haswell`) processor. In a relatively **idle** situation, I ran the following `Perf` commands for **around 5 seconds**. The counters are `offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram` and `offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram`:

```
sudo perf stat -e offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram -p <PID>
```

The workloads are: **1) playing a video** in `VLC` and **2) running** `KDevelop` **indexer** on a large code base. The outputs are shown, **below**:

**VLC:**

```
    Performance counter stats for process id '14617':

         1,621,980      offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                   
         1,611,825      offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                   

       4.993841802 seconds time elapsed
```

**KDevelop:**

```
Performance counter stats for process id '23294':

        31,006,390      offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                   
        10,236,222      offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                   

       5.095681532 seconds time elapsed
```

Based on these statistics, the **memory access frequency** in `KDevelop` is more than **12 times** as much as `VLC`.

But the **IMC counters** statistics (retrieved using [`PCM`](https://github.com/opcm/pcm)) are at **odds** with the above-mentioned **performance counters**. In the **idle** system, the **total system** bandwidth is around `2.65`GB (READ: `2.30`GB, WRITE: `0.35`GB). The total system bandwidth for each workload (ran **separately**) is as follows:

**VLC:**

```
around `8.40`GB (READ:`4.65`GB, WRITE:`3.75`GB)
```

**KDevelop:**

```
around `3.75`GB (READ:`3.15`GB, WRITE:`0.60`GB)
```

After **reducing** the idle system bandwidth, the `VLC` and `KDevelop` bandwidths will be around `5.75`GB and `1.10`GB, respectively. This time, the `VLC` memory access frequency is more than **5 times** as much as `KDevelop`, which shows an obvious **conflict**.

How can these two outcomes be **described**?

Comment: `all_data_rd` is measuring reads, not writes.  But that's still inconsistent with the memory-controller read bandwidth.  The iGPU uses some memory bandwidth itself, and that traffic doesn't come from a core so won't be part of any core's `offcore_response`s.  But I'd expect that to mostly be extra writes, with reads for scan-out being the same as for idle, depending on what video-output driver you're using and how much copying it does (e.g. scaling and post-processing with either VDPAU stuff or pixel shaders for higher quality like `mpv` uses by default.)

Comment: @PeterCordes If the **extra** accesses originate from the **GPU**, why the `I/O` IMC counter is always **stuck** at a constant value?

Comment: Because the GPU and memory controllers are all built-in to the CPU package.  The iGPU talks to the memory controller over the internal ring bus, not over an external PCIe link, so it's not I/O.  (I'm assuming your laptop is using its iGPU because I'ver heard `intel_gpu_top` doesn't work on a system without an iGPU.  If you also have a discrete GPU, disabling the iGPU in the BIOS might give different results.  Some hybrid setups I think have the discrete GPU copy back to the iGPU's video RAM for display, which would cost bandwidth, so just rendering on the discrete GPU might not avoid IMC B/W.)

Comment: @PeterCordes A **turned-off** screen **reduces** the offcore counter values (**both** user and kernel). How can this be described? Why do the **CPU-initiated** memory accesses **change** in the **turned-off** scenario?

Comment: Both **code** and **data** counter values are **reduced**. It seems that the **execution** of some pieces of code and their **associated** data accesses **depend** on the screen **state** (i.e., being turned **on/off**).

Comment: The "offcore" counters might actually be counting all L3 traffic, including cacheable accesses from the iGPU?  I don't know, that's just a guess; some events aren't really core-specific like I think the `unc_*` events, so profiling one program can be disturbed by activity on other cores (or presumably the iGPU).  That could perhaps be the case for the `offcore_` events, too?  And/or there could be errata that affect things.  Or perhaps VLC (or actually the VDPAU library or kernel driver) notices the screen is off and does less work.

Comment: @PeterCordes `perf stat -e instructions` shows **little** difference for the turned **on/off** cases (less than **10 percent**). I also checked the **set of accessed** code pages (using a *Pintool*). They seem to be the **same** in both cases. But memory access stats change, **dramatically** (nearly **4x** for **code**, and **2x** for **data**). I will check with **other** apps.

Comment: The results for `KDevelop` are **OK**. The offcore counter values (**both** user and kernel) are almost **the same** in **both** scenarios (screen **on/off**).

Comment: I also **counted** the number of the executed instructions using another `Pintool`. Turning **off** the screen has **no** effect on the instructions count for `VLC` (**confirms** the similar result obtained from `Perf`). **Similar** instructions cause **smaller** offcore access counts when the screen is **off**!!

Comment: During a **5 second video streaming** in VLC, **sampling** `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:uppp` (period 1000) shows **184** and **1** instance(s) of `ThreadDisplayRenderPicture()` in the backtraces of the **turned-on** and **turned-off** screen scenarios, respectively. This function is called by a **dedicated thread** called `ThreadDisplayRenderPicture`. In other words, it seems that `ThreadDisplayRenderPicture` **stops** rendering pictures when the screen is **off**. I **didn't** do a **detailed** analysis on the sampled backtraces. Perhaps the two scenarios have **more** differences.

Comment: To be more **precise**, **184 out of 285** samples **versus** **1 out of 83** samples.